# ASPxGridView and LinqServerModeDataSource, inserting rows by stored procedure

Tags: devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a page using ASPxGridView and to fill the GridView I use a LinqServerModeDataSource control who fetches it data through a SQL View from a MS SQL Server. So far so good but here comes the problem.

I want to insert data in the database so I'm building a custom form

```
<Templates>
    <EditForm>
        Company Name: <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="CompanyName" runat="server" />
        Company Mail: <dx:ASPxTextBox ID="Email" runat="server" />

        <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="UpdateButton" ReplacementType="EditFormUpdateButton" runat="server" />
        <dx:ASPxGridViewTemplateReplacement ID="CancelButton" ReplacementType="EditFormCancelButton" runat="server" />

    </EditForm>
</Templates>
```

Here is an example of the custom form

[image: Example]

Pretty basic stuff, in this scenario the Company name goes to one table and the email to another. This is all handled by calling a Stored Procedure. Or thats the plan.

Does anyone know how to do this?

It feels like I've been trying it all, LinqServerModeDataSource1_Inserting, ASPxGridView1_RowInserting and so on but nooo. Here is one of the failing codes. And the devexpress documentation is even worse, but lets not go there its not a happy place.

```
protected void LinqServerModeDataSource1_Inserting(object sender, DevExpress.Data.Linq.LinqServerModeDataSourceEditEventArgs e)
{
    // Some magic to insert data here
    ASPxGridView1.CancelEdit();
}
```

So, any advice or help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I want to insert data in the database so I'm building a custom form" ASPxGridView can do all that for you without you having to make a custom template at least with sqldb
If i would define a delete command and or edit command below to the sqldatasource i could already delete and edit the information in the gridview

```
  <dx:ASPxGridView ID="ASPxGridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        ClientIDMode="AutoID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <Columns>
            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0">
                <EditButton Visible="True">
                </EditButton>
                <NewButton Visible="True">
                </NewButton>
                <DeleteButton Visible="True">
                </DeleteButton>
            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Naam" VisibleIndex="0">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Adres" VisibleIndex="1">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Postcode" VisibleIndex="2">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Plaats" VisibleIndex="3">
            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        </Columns>
    </dx:ASPxGridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [Address], [Postcode], [City] FROM [Somewhere]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

But you can if you really want to use a custom made insert or delete

```
protected void ASPxGridView4_RowDeleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
{
    DataColumn[] esl = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["SQLWaarde"] };
    if (ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey == null || ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey == esl)
    {
        ds.Tables[0].PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["SQLWaarde"] };
    }
    DataRow[] delRow = ds2.Tables[0].Select("IndWaardeType = '" + e.Values[1] + "' AND SQLWaarde = '" + e.Values[2] + "'");
    ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Remove(delRow[0] as DataRow);

    e.Cancel = true;
    ASPxGridView4.CancelEdit();
    Session["ds2"] = ds2;
}
protected void ASPxGridView4_RowInserting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataInsertingEventArgs e)
{
    ndr2 = ds2.Tables[0].NewRow();
    ndr2[0] = e.NewValues[0];
    ndr2[1] = e.NewValues[1];
    ndr2[2] = e.NewValues[2];
    ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ndr2);

    e.Cancel = true;
    ASPxGridView4.CancelEdit();
    Session["ds2"] = ds2;
}
```

That's how i did it last time. I made use of datatables and stored that in sessions bla bla realy just trying out but it works alright.